# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'firstName' cannot be null (23000)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am in the way of learning laravel and at this point I am trying to send a query back to my database from a basic from that i build using CoreUI as an admin template.

So basically i get this error:

```
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'firstName' cannot be null (23000)
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'firstName' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `clients` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `companyName`, `phone`, `email`, `password`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `postcode`, `country`, `notes`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , , , , , , , , , 2020-10-19 01:41:04, 2020-10-19 01:41:04))
```

Previous exceptions

and my clientscontroller.php includes this code

```
use App\Client;
public function store(Request $req){
    $client = new Client;
    $client->firstName = $req->firstName;
    $client->lastName = $req->lastName;
    $client->companyName = $req->companyName;
    $client->phone = $req->phone;
    $client->email = $req->email;
    $client->password = $req->password;
    $client->address1 = $req->address1;
    $client->address2 = $req->address2;
    $client->city = $req->city;
    $client->postcode = $req->postcode;
    $client->country = $req->country; 
    $client->notes = $req->notes;
    $client->save();
    return redirect('addclient')->with('status','Client added successfully!');
}
```

in my model client.php i have include nothing because i seen 20 tutorials but nowhere i could able to find what should i do so i have just included those 2

```
     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

the routes i think are correct
so does anyone knows what do i miss because on the web there is no clear way of sending data from the blade to the mysql.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Here is the form:

```
 <h4 class="card-title">Add new Client</h4>
            <p class="card-description">Enter customer information</p>
        <form action="{{route('save')}}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="John">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Doe">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="companyName">Company Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="WEBSUNRISE">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="+44.7545958574">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing `$req->firstName;` to `$req->input('firstName');` and do the same for all of the other inputs.

Comment: You can use debugging functions like `dd()` to check if either `$req->firstName` or `$client->firstName` is set correctly as you sent on the request.

Comment: Is there any other way more updated that I could do the same action or any more secure or thats all?

Comment: @ElektaKode Can you show me an example?

Comment: @RafMavrogordatos : Try `dd($req->firstName)` at the first line of `store` method and see the result.

Comment: It comes null for the firstname and based with the previous error null all the form elements. based on my files that i attached the code is anything that I am doing wrong or missing? because i fullfill the form and the data gets null from the controller to my db?

Comment: Try following link to see how to get payload data from request object in Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests

Comment: Does the form field names match those that you are calling from the request?

Comment: @StevenPss Yes look at my code

Comment: Where's your form? I think, it is problem with your form? Since, your data is not getting from client side.

Comment: did you added `firstName` on your Models's `fillable=[]` property?

Comment: Please provide the form from which you input the values, can't do much but speculate right now. The CoreUI template form that contains the fields that your are requesting in your controller.

Comment: @StevenPss I edited the post

Comment: oooo maybe i should include name on the input values? hahahahha

Comment: Yes do that. If it works mark @M Pillai answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: He should post the answer individually to assign the accepted answer to hip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$req->input('firstName')`. Also, check whether there is an input tag with name of firstName, lastName and even for the rest, in HTML Form. Giving a name to input tag is necessary, as we take value using **name** in Laravel. I feel, in your case, you might have missed it, as not for just firstName, even for the rest fields, it is not taking any value.

So, at first check,in Form:

```
<input type = "text" name = "firstName" placeholder = "Give name in each input tag">
```

If still doesn't work, try

```
$client->firstName = $req->firstName;
```